# Linear solenoid specifications

Tags: power-supply, solenoid, buying

I want to buy a linear solenoid that has the following specifications in the Datasheet:

- 24 VDC
- 9W 100% Duty Cycle
- 18W 50% Duty Cycle
- 36W 25% Duty Cycle
- 90W 10% Duty Cycle

And the following force-stroke curves:

[image]

I have a power supply of 24VDC and 10A. Since I don't know the coil resistance (at 20 °C), how can I know the current that would go through the coil?

In other words, do I have to assume that at 24V the curve that represents the behaviour of the solenoid corresponds to 100% duty cycle and 9W? And the other curves are only for higher voltages than the rated voltage of 24 V?

Comment: Decent datasheets should specify the current vs actuation/field strength/something. The graph you linked doesn't tell a thing. Do you have a link to the datasheet? Though in case 24V can be regarded as 24.00V in this example, you can probably calculate the currents based on power. Just note than in a real application, voltage and resistance will vary, you should regulate it with constant current.

Comment: The link of the datasheet is [link](https://docs.rs-online.com/f012/0900766b8167924c.pdf) . I was aware of the varaition of resistance due to a temperature increase (which translates to a current decrease), but I thought voltage should remain constant during operation.

Comment: Depends a lot on the application. You should also have some graph in the datasheet showing temperature curves. What you linked isn't a datasheet, it is a product brief labelled "datasheet". Don't buy crap that doesn't come with proper documentation.

Comment: You need to know the resistance. Ask the vendor; or find a better one.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I have a power supply of 24VDC and 10A. Since I don't know the coil
> resistance (at 20 °C), how can I know the current that would go
> through the coil?*

From the information you state....

> - *24 VDC*
> - *9W 100% Duty Cycle*

It's a fair assumption that the current from a 24 volt supply would be 375 mA or thereabouts. The solenoid would have a DC resistance of 64 Ω.

- *90W 10% Duty Cycle*

That's basically an average of 9 watts i.e. 90 watts for 10 percent of the time. That puts an upper limit on the pulsed voltage of 75.89 volts because: -

$$\text{Voltage}_{MAX} = \sqrt{Power\times Resistance}$$

Comment: Very useful, thanks! So using my power supply (24V 10A) I guess I should expect a force-stroke curve like the green one? Anyways I will try to find a better documented product.

Comment: Yes, the green curve applies to a constant 24 volts applied.